# Correct SQL expression for SelectbyAttribute Tool

Tags: arcpy, sql, select-by-attribute, nameerror

I'm trying to apply the sql expression described here https://geonet.esri.com/thread/76028, that involves querying out odd values in a field. The specific sql expression is `Round(NumberField / 2, 0) <> NumberField / 2`.

I've written this in python:

```
import arcpy

plantFile = r"U:\Users\K\Plants.shp"
field = "UID"

expression = Round("UID" / 2, 0) <> "UID" / 2
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(plantFile, "NEW_SELECTION", expression)
```

and it returns this error: NameError: name 'Round' is not defined

The expression works when applied in ArcGIS, but not in arcpy. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Python is case-sensitive so the first error you are seeing is due to the Python interpreter seeing `Round` and trying to find a function of that name.

To see that it recognizes `round` but not `Round` try:

```
Python 2.7.12 (v2.7.12:d33e0cf91556, Jun 27 2016, 15:19:22) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> Round

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    Round
NameError: name 'Round' is not defined
>>> round
<built-in function round>
>>>
```

However, you actually need to either single (') or triple single quote (''') your `expression` variable so that you can pass it to SelectByAttributes as an SQL expression.

There the SQL interpreter would not care about the case of the `Round` function, as highlighted by @Vince in his comment.

Comment: Thank you, this worked! Although now I have a follow-up problem, which I'll make another post for.

Comment: Isn't the problem that the "expression" wasn't quoted, as in `expression = 'Round("UID" / 2, 0) <> "UID" / 2'`?

Comment: @Vince I'm expecting that will be the next error encountered but the mixed case Round needs to be dealt with first.

Comment: SQL doesn't care about case. The goal is to generate a SQL expression.

Comment: @Vince I should have tested more before answering but what you say makes sense so I'll revise my answer when I can get to a laptop.

Comment: It's answered in the follow-on Q.